# Which test to use for associations between categorical independent and ordinal outcome

Tags: statistical-significance, stata, ordinal-data

I am analyzing factors that influence program retention in a medical program. Our dependent variable, retention time, is split into 4 categories (<1 month, 1-3 months, 3.1-6 months and >6 months). Independent variables are categorical (race, gender, disease status, housing status, etc.). Some independent variables have 2 groups (ex. gender), others have multiple groups (ex. race).
I believe our dependent variable is considered ordinal data.
We are looking for to test associations between independent variables and the dependent variable. Our group of analysts is conflicted over which test is more appropriate-- Pearsons Chi Square, Spearmans Chi Square or some other test?

Thanks in advance for any insight and supporting explanation. We're using STATA.

Comment: Look into ordinal regression, search this site